# How to arrange data from row to column wise?

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Question Updated:

I have data in rows in two columns.

[image]

There is heading mismatch of every iteration. I want data like below. where data not there that specific head it will be empty in that row.

[image]

I have used below formula, but it is not working as space is not taking in cell where head is missing in iteration.

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$18,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$18=D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$18)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$18))+1),ROWS($D$2:D2))),"")

A: heading column

B: data column

D: starting column of calculation

it is resulting in below format which is not desired result.

[image]

Comment: please see  read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Check out transpose()

Comment: Transpose will not work as we have more than 200 thousand lines of row.

Comment: How do you want this done? Add the appropriate tags e.g. `excel-formula`, `vba`... Also, explain the layout of your data and add at least one more set so it can be better understood. Share it in text format best by using the [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Nobody wants to write hundreds of characters of random text. By the looks of it, one could conclude that each set occupies 7 rows followed by a blank row. I am assuming that the destination headers will be part of the inputs. Please clarify by editing your post (not in the comments).

Comment: I have edited question for better understanding and the method I tried.

Answer (score 0):

'll assume that your source data is in columns A and B, starting at row 2.
I am initially also assuming that rows are all consistent.
In D2 enter =B2
In E2 enter =B3
Carry on until you have all data for the first record.

Then the clever bit:

- put some character, E.g. 1, in column C from the top to the bottom
  (enter in C2, Edit|Copy C2, F5 to C200000, Edit|Paste, F8, CTRL-Up_arrow, Paste)
- select from D2 across to include all the new columns and down *to the last blank row before the second record*.
- put cursor on the bottom right-hand corner, and double-click on the cross.

Instant!
If you have auto-calculate off, press F9.
There is your data.
To use it, copy the whole of columns D to N and on a new sheet Paste Special|Values.
Then you can sort to remove the blank rows.
And add the field-names at the top with a Paste | Transpose.

---

If the rows of the input data are not consistent, this approach still works as a base, but you need to add some elements.
E.g. if number of blank rows between records varies, pre-process by adding an Index column with 1 to X in it, sort everything by the values in Column B, remove the blank rows at the bottom, and resort by the Index.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

*(Assumes each "set" is separated by at least one blank row
If that is not the case, additional coding will be required)*

To use Power Query

- Select your entire data range

  - Format as table
- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

//create a table of all needed column headers and a sorting column
//assumes all have same prefix - underscore - sequential number
    #"All Columns" = 
        let 
            prefix = Text.Split(#"Changed Type"[Column1]{0},"_"){0} & "_",
            allNums = List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Column1], 
                each try Number.From(Text.Split(_, "_"){1}) otherwise null)),
            start = List.Min(allNums),
            end = List.Max(allNums),
            nums = List.Numbers(start, end-start+1,1),
            cols = List.Transform(nums, each prefix & Text.From(_))
        in 
            Table.FromColumns(
                {cols} & {nums},
                type table[AllHdrs=text, Sort=Int64.Type]),

//add column to group each section
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Grouper", each if [Column1] = null then [Index] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Removed Columns",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each ([Column1] <> null)),

//group by each section
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Grouper"}, {

    //merge with all col names
        {"all", (t)=>
            let 
                clean = Table.RemoveColumns(t,{"Grouper"}),
                merge = Table.Join(clean, "Column1", #"All Columns", "AllHdrs", JoinKind.FullOuter),
                clean2 = Table.RemoveColumns(merge,{"Column1"}),
                sort = Table.Sort(clean2, {"Sort", Order.Ascending}),
                clean3 = Table.RemoveColumns(sort,{"Sort"}),
                pivot = Table.Pivot(clean3,clean3[AllHdrs],"AllHdrs","Column2")
            in 
                pivot}
        }),

    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "all", #"All Columns"[AllHdrs]),
    #"Change Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded all", List.Transform(#"All Columns"[AllHdrs], each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Change Type2"
```

**Original**
[image]

**Result**
[image]